# podio api file upload from url

Tags: php, api, podio

Have tried the API call as listed on Podio dev site to upload a file and I am not getting much joy.

I am trying to "Upload a file" in the first instance using the POST operation and passing the json with the source url to the endpoint as specified.

I can use other methods just fine but since there is little in the way or error feedback I am stuck I keep getting error 404

I have used - https://developers.podio.com/doc/files/upload-file-1004361

(have tried both GET & POST)
[image of method with error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qajL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Upload file method that you are trying to use (https://developers.podio.com/doc/files/upload-file-1004361) is expecting file path which is supposed to be local file but not url.

Here is example of how it should be used:
http://podio.github.io/podio-php/api-requests/

```
$file = PodioFile::upload($path_to_file, $filename_to_display);
print 'File uploaded. The file id is: '.$file->id;
```

Here is another example on how to work with files:
https://developers.podio.com/examples/files

Comment: Perfect .. I had seen conflicting reports in reference to URL for the $path_to_file and thought maybe its universal ... so its only good for local uploads and not able to fetch from a HTTP URL path.

many thanks will look for an alternative to solve this.

Comment: You can always download that file to local disk first, and then upload to Podio :)